# Mongodb - Concatenate multiple nested arrays and convert to a string

Tags: mongodb, concatenation

I have the following documents

```
{"_id": "1", "posts": [{"text": "all day long I dream about", "datetime": "123"}, {"text": "all day long ", "datetime": "321"}]}
{"_id": "1", "posts": [{"text": "all day long I dream about", "datetime": "123"}, {"text": "all day long ", "datetime": "8888"}, {"text": "I became very hungry after watching this movie...", "datetime": "8885"}]}
```

I wish to concatenate the **text** fields into a new field and the **datetime** field into a new field while also joining the arrays elements into a string in a way that the new field will be as follows

```
{"_id": "1", "text": "all day long I dream about, all day long ", "datetime": "123, 321"}
{"_id": "1", "text": "all day long I dream about, all day long ,I became very hungry after watching this movie... ", "datetime": "123, 8888, 8885"}
```

What's the best way of doing that directly on Mongodb server? Is there such way?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Query

- reduce on posts starting with `null` (same code 2x)
- if not null `(concat all_string ", " current_string)`
- else `current_string` (this happens only for the first string)

*that check if not `null` is only for the first string, to not have something like  ", string1, string2 ...." we do this to avoid add `,` to the first string
*you could do it with 1 reduce also, but code would be more complicated

[Test code here](https://cmql.org/play/?q=70608671-m)

```js
aggregate(
[{"$set":
  {"text":
   {"$reduce":
    {"input":"$posts",
     "initialValue":null,
     "in":
     {"$cond":
      ["$$value", {"$concat":["$$value", ", ", "$$this.text"]},
       "$$this.text"]}}}}},
 {"$set":
  {"datetime":
   {"$reduce":
    {"input":"$posts",
     "initialValue":null,
     "in":
     {"$cond":
      ["$$value", {"$concat":["$$value", ", ", "$$this.datetime"]},
       "$$this.datetime"]}}}}}
 {"$unset":["posts"]}])
```

Comment: Works perfectly and you explanation is blessed. Thank you.

Comment: Let's say I want to create a new string of 'datetime' even when all the values are null, for example - "null, null, null..."
How would I do that?

Comment: i think you need [this](https://cmql.org/play/?q=1641747018911) , it uses one variable, if datetime is null, then it is as it it was "null" , else has the normal datetime value.

Comment: You are a magician. Thank you so much, you helped me a lot.